# Stop users from locking up crashing Linux machine using simple C code

Tags: linux, process, fork, denial-of-service

Is there a way to prevent users from locking up a linux machine with code something along the lines of:

```
#import <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    while (1)
        fork();
}
```

The computers in question are in a computer lab, so I can't exactly disallow compiling... but is there some way of ensuring such processes only consume a certain portion of the system resources? The importance of this issue is compounded by the fact that any user can ssh into any of the systems, so really the only reason this hasn't become a problem yet is most users are more or less unfamiliar with C or other low-level languages.

Still, I'd like to nip this one in the bud...

Comment: Tell them not to? Sounds like more of a disciplinary problem than a programming problem.

Comment: It's not a problem at the moment - I just don't think the "nobody's abusing it and we tell them not to so they won't" approach isn't a particularly good one

Comment: And trust all those hacker-wannabies of behaving nice? :>

Comment: You don't need to trust them.  You just figure out who is responsible and have them suspended from using the Lab for violating the acceptable use policy.

Comment: What, and tell them not to experiment? If some kid outsmarts me, I'd rather learn from him than yell at him. Bottom line is we have to be secure, not rely on people to be good. For example, if one of the students passwords got out, anyone could log in. Do you suspend a kid for someone figuring out or finding his password?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can limit the total number of concurrent processes that each user is allowed to create. I think it's in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and the `NPROC` field is what you need to set.

*Update:* Just looked it up [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-limiting-user-process.html) and it appears my memory isn't failing me after all :-)

The simplest way is to enter:

```
* hard nproc 50
```

which will limit all users to 50 processes. You may want to have a little more fine-grained control than that.

Alternatively, you can use `ulimit` to enforce the limit if `limits.conf` is not available on your system. You will have to ensure that all started processes are restricted by, for example, putting it into `/etc/profile` and all other possible entry points:

```
ulimit -Hu 50
```

Comment: +1 because this has saved me from countless resource overruns over the years.

Answer (score 6):

See Wikipedia on [Fork Bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb), section "Prevention".